# Checking circular primes in Prolog

Tags: prolog, primes

I am new to Prolog and am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code.
I am trying to find [circular prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_prime)
So far I have this code:

```
isCircularPrime(N):-
    prime(N),
    numDigits(N, Y),
    Y2 is Y-1,
    rotate(N,Y,N2),
    circularPrime(N2, Y2, Y2).

circularPrime(_, 0, _).     
circularPrime(N, 1, _):-prime(N).
circularPrime(N, I, J):-
    I > 1,
    prime(N),
    I2 is I-1,
    rotate(N,J,N2),
    circularPrime(N2,I2,J).
```

Where:

- numDigits makes Y the number of digits in N.
- rotate makes N2 a rotation of N (e.g. 12 -> 21).
- prime is true if N is prime, false otherwise

Currently it recurses infinitely whenever a number is prime but not a circular prime (e.g. 19, 23, etc).  If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the other code in case anyone wants to test this for themselves:

```
prime(2).
prime(3).
prime(N):-
    N>3,
    N mod 2 =\= 0,
    \+ divisible(N,3).

divisible(N,I):- N mod I =:= 0.
divisible(N,I):-
    I*I < N,
    I2 is I + 2,
    divisible(N, I2).

numDigits(N, 1):- 
    N<10, N>0.
numDigits(N, X):- 
    N2 is N/10, 
    numDigits(N2, Y), 
    X is (Y+1).

rotate(N, L, R):-
    LastDigit is N mod 10,
    Base is div(N, 10),
    Exponent is L - 1,
    Num is 10**Exponent,
    NewBase is LastDigit*Num,
    R is Base + NewBase.
```

Comment: Rather use `^` in place of `**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `numDigits/2` predicate.

It offers all kinds of answers, so the program keeps backtracking again and again:

```
numDigits(1, X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 etc...
```

After adding cuts to `numDigits/2` the programs seems to behave correctly:

```
isCircularPrime(19).
false.
```